# Silent Outlook popups regarding self-signed certificate when connecting to pop3-ssl server

Tags: outlook, ssl-certificate, pop3

When MS Outlook (2003/2007/2010) connect to pop3-ssl server and the server certificate is selfsigned it opens a dialog whether or not user wants to accept it. Is it possible to suppress this message like it is with Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

That opens the dialog because it wants to make the user aware that it is accepting a self-signed certificate. Typically if you're using a self-signed certificate in the environment it's important to allow the user to verify it.

That aside -- if you do not have a domain, you can do it manually you'll just have to install the certificate when the pop up appears. You should be able to click 'more details' and then 'Install Certificate'.

Answer (score 0):

Add the certificate to the computer's [certificate store](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757138(WS.10).aspx).  If your computers are in the domain you should be able to do this by group policy.